# the difference between the two syntax "$!" and "$?"

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, aix

I've been working on Shell and I've seen something like :

```
pid_A2=$!
wait $pid_A2
pid_A2=$?
```

Would you please explain the difference between the two syntax "$!" and "$?"...
Actually, i know that $? is the exit status of the previous command but I've never seen the previous one.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287442/exclamation-mark-variable/287445

Comment: It would be good to show the line *before* `pid_A2=$!` -- it's probably something like: `some_command &` where the command is launched in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$!` is the last job of the background process. For example:

```
$ sleep 1000 &
[1] 6646    ---> process id
```

`echo "$!"` will print the process id of the last command (here, 6646).

`$?` returns the exit value of the command which is recently executed. `$?` is used when we want to handle the return value of a command or function. For example:

```
if [ **$?** -eq 1 ];
then
    # do something
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`$?`: the status of the last process execution

`$!`: the pid of the last command in background